# rootview.findViewById() is not working in fragment file

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

```
package com.example.mayank.sunshine;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String[] forecastArray = {
            "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
            "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40",
            "Weds - Cloudy - 727/63",
            "Thurs - Asteroids - 75/65",
            "Fri - Heavy Rain - 65/56",
            "Sat - HELP TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 60/51",
            "Sun - Sunny - 80/68"
        };

        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

        mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.list_item_forecast,
            R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
            weekForecast);

        ListView listView = (ListView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);

        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
}
```

Running the project shows compilation error "cannot find symbol variable rootview". Do I have to import anything to run the code?

P.S. I am using Android Studio 1.4 which, by deafult, builds a seperate java file for fragments.

Comment: why not use getView() ?

Comment: before copy pasting a code, try to understand what it is. It's showing "cannot find symbol variable" because there is no such variable/field in your code.

Comment: rootView is not even assigned before making a call on it. and what were you planning there, extract a list view from a null entity and later inflate your own layout on the fragment? In short, onCreate is meant to return a view which you need displayed. inflate first and then extract list view from rootView and then return rootView

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I am new to android development and I don't have any knowledge about getView()

Comment: @stack_ved Thanks for the explaination. Being a beginner, I couldn't understand the error properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `onCreateView()` you have to `inflate` your `rootView` you can do like this ->

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,    false);

....
return rootView;
```

Comment: Great, you can accept it so it clears the **unanswered questions** queue

Comment: Oh sorry. It was my first question here, so didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

you have to get your rootview first before get something from it.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout, container, false); 
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout); return rootView; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the error because you have not inflated your layout inside rootview variable. first declare a View type variable say rootView as local or global then inflate your layout in rootView and then use rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
here is the complete code you are using

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
    private View rootView;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        String[] forecastArray = {
            "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
            "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40",
            "Weds - Cloudy - 727/63",
            "Thurs - Asteroids - 75/65",
            "Fri - Heavy Rain - 65/56",
            "Sat - HELP TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 60/51",
            "Sun - Sunny - 80/68"
        };

        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

        mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.list_item_forecast,
            R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
            weekForecast);

        ListView listView = (ListView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

just replace your code with this one it will work :-)